# Supabase bandthwith. Is File/Image Upload/Download included as bandwidth usage?

Tags: supabase

I am planing to use supabase. Just want to to know what are the scope of bandwidth usage.

Does Image Upload /Download considered a bandwith usage

What else?
Thanks

None so far. Just read other resources but couldn't find answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [Supabase's pricing page](https://supabase.com/pricing) under `Bandwidth` it states the following:

> Billing is based on the total sum of outgoing traffic (includes Database, Storage, Realtime, Auth) in GB throughout your billing period.